# How do you pass a Javascript variable to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
   var list_max = 99
</script>

<div>
  <input type="text" data-index="0" name="min" value="1"/>
  <input type="text" data-index="1" name="max" value="list_max"/>
</div>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SP5VQ/10/

So you have a variable in Javascript, and you want to pass it into the value of an HTML input. What do you do?

In order to make the html code function like this

```
<input type="text" data-index="0" name="min" value="1"/>
<input type="text" data-index="1" name="max" value="99"/>
```

Comment: With the DOM API. http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#JavaScript_core_skills

Comment: Sorry guys, I am new to web-programming.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's answer though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assign an `id` to the input, like this:

```
<input type="text" id="list_max" data-index="1" name="max" />
```

Then you can assign the value using JS like this:

```
document.getElementById('list_max').value = list_max;
```

I'm assuming you're running the JS code within a function that will get executed after the page is loaded. If not, make sure you either run it after the relevant HTML, or wrap it in a `window.onload = function() { /* ... */ };`.

Comment: An `id` is *one* way to do it, yes. On [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) you could use `document.querySelector("input[name=max]")` instead, or do something more structural. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder using an `id` is the *fastest* way to do it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Don't you think that's a bit of overkill for this question? Plus, wouldn't a simple solution that works in all browsers be a better idea? Thanks for the link, though. Looks quite useful.

Comment: @bfontaine: In absolute terms, sure. There's no human-detectable difference whatsoever. If you're going to do 10k of these in a tight loop, then you're probably going to want to do it differently in any case. :-)

Comment: @Travesty3: I wasn't dissing the answer, I hope you didn't get that impression. Just adding a further option. Remember that `id` values become global variables, which is not a good thing sometimes, and a lot of the time you're working within a structure where there are better ways to get the element you want. The only concern about using qs/qsa is IE6 or IE7, which outside of very specific requirements or web sites for the Chinese market, just aren't an issue anymore.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: No worries, I didn't take it badly. I just wanted to make sure the OP (who has confirmed that he is a newbie to web programming) figured out the basics before using something more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" data-index="1" name="max" id="myElement" />
<script>
   document.getElementById('myElement').value = 99;
</script>
```

Comment: This won't work because your script is invoked before the element exists.

Comment: That will error. There is no element with that id when the script runs.

Comment: thanks guys, corrected it! copied that in afterwards (shame on me)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" data-index="0" name="min" value="1"/>
<input type="text" data-index="1" id='change_me' name="max" value="99"/>

<script>
var list_max = 99
document.getElementById("change_me").value = list_max ;
</script>
```

in any case use onload so it runs after the page loads:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

google is your friend.

Comment: W3Schools, otoh, is your enemy. c.f. http://w3fools.com/

Comment: i didn't say they were the best, i like net tuts better.

Answer (score -1):

If you use jQuery

```
<input type="text" data-index="0" name="min" value="1"/>
<input type="text" data-index="1" id='change_me' name="max" value="99"/>

<script>
var list_max = 99
$('input[name="max"]').val(list_max);
</script>
```